# How to add keys but not values to later on add values in a switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

i have a switch which goes through an excell document and takes all values from different colums at different times. I am getting one value in case 1 in a switch and then one in case 2 and so fourth. But if i wanna add this values first in case 1 as a key and then case 2 as a value how would i go about this?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < CorrectColumn.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < rows; j++)
            {
               switch (i)
               {
                    case 1:
                        categories1.Category.Add(excellObj.getValuesFromCell(j, CorrectColumn[i]), null);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        categories1.Category.Add(null, excellObj.getValuesFromCell(j, CorrectColumn[i]));
                        break;
               }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: i have now done so

Answer (score 0):

do it like this, then it will work,
in the following assumption:

1. key and value are specified within the same row of the sheet.
2. the key and value are always in the same columns of your sheet.

```
        for (int j = 2; j < rows; j++)
        {
            object key = null;
            object value = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < CorrectColumn.Count; i++)
            {
               switch (i)
               {
                    case 1:
                        key = excellObj.getValuesFromCell(j, CorrectColumn[i]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        value = excellObj.getValuesFromCell(j, CorrectColumn[i]);
                        break;
               }
            }
            categories1.Category.Add(key, value);


         }
```